# Understanding Theorem 7.2. of Titchmarsh's Book

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, summation

The following is Theorem 7.2. in Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

I cannot figure out how the underlined equality above holds. In LHS t is greater than both n and m thus greater than max(n,m) but how it changes the sums from $\sum_{<t}$ to $\sum_{<T}$ and the integral is zero for $\max (n,m)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with
$$\int_1^T\sum_{m<t}m^{-\sigma-it}\sum_{n<t}n^{-\sigma+it}dt$$
we can distribute the $m$ sum over the $n$ sum and factor out some factors of $m$ and $n$ to get
$$=\int_1^T\sum_{m<t}\sum_{n<t}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
we're taking $T$ to infinity, so let's assume without loss of generality that $T$ is an integer. We can then split the integral like so:
$$=\sum_{a=1}^{T-1}\int_{a}^{a+1}\sum_{m<t}\sum_{n<t}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
Now note that the variable of integration takes a uniform integer part over the interval of integration, so the bounds on the sums can be fixed and then the integral distributes all the way over (take care that the summation variable should *take* the lower bound of the integral, so it is *less than* the lower bound plus 1):
$$=\sum_{a=1}^{T-1}\sum_{m<a+1}\sum_{n<a+1}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\int_{a}^{a+1}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
With some care we can distribute the outer sum through as well. This is where the max shows up! It's not super intuitive in my opinion, but it's discrete here, so it's just a matter of combinatorics to convince yourself of correctness:
$$=\sum_{m<T}\sum_{a=m}^{T-1}\sum_{n<a}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\int_{a}^{a+1}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
$$=\sum_{m<T}\sum_{n<T}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\sum_{a=T_1}^{T-1}\int_{a}^{a+1}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
Now the far right sum is just an integral broken into intervals, which we can adjoin again:
$$=\sum_{m<T}\sum_{n<T}m^{-\sigma}n^{-\sigma}\int_{T_1}^{T}\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{it}dt$$
as was desired.

I've omitted it due to it mostly obscuring the derivation with tedious details, but you may be interested in assuring yourself that this holds approximately for non-integer $T$. The derivation goes similarly, except you break the integral into the unit intervals and a left-over bit, and carefully factor out the left-over bits. You will find that the left-overs concern $n\approx m\approx T$ and thus are at most $O(T^{-2\sigma})$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "Now note that t has a uniform integer part over the interval of integration"? What is "has a uniform integer part"?

Comment: @Ali The interval of integration will always be between two consecutive integers: a is an integer, as is a+1. Because of this, the greatest integer less than the variable of integration t will always be a, so we can bound the sums by a+1.

Comment: When you pass integral through the double sum why do you change upper sum from t to a+1? That is, how $\int_a^{a+1} \sum_{n<t} \sum_{m<t} = \sum_{n<a+1} \sum_{m<a+1} \int_a^{a+1}$?

Comment: @Ali t is always greater than a, and less than a+1, so n and m will range from 1 to a. It is thus equivalent to use an upper limit of a+1.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)